# Always run lifecycle phase (e.g. package) before goal (e.g. exec:exec)

Tags: java, maven, exec-maven-plugin

I'm trying to get into maven and started writing just a small library. As part of the library code I want to have a small demo java application one can use to see what the library is doing and how to use it. One thing that really annoys me right now is that in order to execute that demo I have to execute two commands: `mvn package` and `mvn exec:exec` or `mvn package exec:exec`.

Is there any way to configure maven to automatically run "package" before "exec:exec"? So that I can run `mvn exec:exec` on a fresh checkout and compilation will implicitly happen before execution?

Answer (score 2):

`mvn package exec:exec`

You can specify multiple goals for Maven to execute as part of the same command.

Additionally, when you configure the `exec` plugin, you can bind the execution to the `package` phase: [Lifecycle Intro](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Built-in_Lifecycle_Bindings)

Comment: well, I already find typing "exec:exec" cumbersome, if possible I'd rather type "mvn run" or "mvn exec". Sorry, forgot to mention that in the question. It just seems weird to have the only way possible to start the application ("mvn exec:exec") not working by default.

Comment: That's a different question, then. If it's a matter of saving keystrokes, alias it in your shell, or set up a run configuration in Eclipse/Netbeans/your IDE of choice.